# Comparator interface

Tags: java

ok I was going to edit my previous question but i wasnt sure if it was the right way to do it so i'll just give another question about Comparator, now i want to be able to sort with different ways. I have a bank checks and i want to sort with checkNumber then checkAmount
i managed to do it with checkNumber but couldnt figure out how with checkAmount
here is how i did it for checkNumber:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Check implements Comparator {
    private int checkNumber;
    private String description;
    private double checkAmount;

    public Check() {


    }


    public Check(int newCheckNumber, double newAmountNumber) {

        setCheckNumber(newCheckNumber);
        setAmountNumber(newAmountNumber);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return  checkNumber + "\t\t" + checkAmount;
    }

    public void setCheckNumber(int checkNumber) {
        this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
    }

    public int getCheckNumber() {
        return checkNumber;
    }

    public void setAmountNumber(double amountNumber) {
        this.checkAmount = amountNumber;
    }

    public double getAmountNumber() {
        return checkAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {

         int value1 = ((Check) obj1).getCheckNumber();
        int value2 = ((Check) obj2).getCheckNumber();

         int result = 0;

         if (value1 > value2){
             result = 1;
         }
         else if(value1 < value2){
             result = -1;
         }
         return result;
    }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import test.CheckValue;

public class TestCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList List = new ArrayList();


        List.add(new Check(445, 55.0));
        List.add(new Check(101,43.12));
        List.add(new Check(110,101.0));
        List.add(new Check(553,300.21));
        List.add(new Check(123,32.1));


        Collections.sort(List, new Check());

        System.out.println("Check Number - Check Amount");

        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++){

            System.out.println(List.get(i));
        }



    }

}
```

thank you very much in advance and please tell me if im submiting things in the wrong way.

Comment: You could shorten your code and remove everything that's not related to your current problem. This way more people are willing to read it and you will get more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want to do is define a *separate* class to act as the `Comparator` object - don't make your actual `Check` class the comparator, but instead have 3 classes:

1. the `Check` class itself
2. a `CheckAmountComparator` class (or something similar) that implements `Comparator<Check>`
3. a `CheckNumberComparator` class (or something similar) that implements `Comparator<Check>`

Then when you want to sort one way or another, you simply pass an instance of the `Comparator`-implementing class corresponding to the type of sorting you want to do. For instance, to sort by amount, it'd then become...

```
Collections.sort(yourListVariable, new CheckAmountComparator());
```

*Also - I'd highly suggest naming your variable something other than `List`, since List is used as a type name in Java.*

Comment: you know what you really making sense! the instructor also suggested to use separate classes but i somehow ignored it :/

Comment: how would a do it for a type double which is AmountCheck though?

Comment: Should be able to do it the same way you would for `int` except your `value1` and `value2` would need to be `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: i dont know how i did it but it worked lol.
I added a method 
public double getCheckAmount() {
  return checkAmount;
}
in Check Class and it worked. could you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

You should make `Check implements Comparable<Check>`, but not itself `implements Comparator`.

A `Comparable` type defines *the* natural ordering for the type, and a `Comparator` for a type is usually not the type itself, and defines their own custom ordering of that type.

#### Related questions

- [When to use Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator)
- [Java: What is the difference between implementing Comparable and Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator)
- [Can I use a Comparator without implementing Comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864034/can-i-use-a-comparator-without-implementing-comparable)

---

Also, you shouldn't use raw type. You need to use parameterized generic types, `Comparable<Check>`, `Comparator<Check>`, `List<Check>`, etc.

#### Related questions

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn’t we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

#### A `String` example

Let's take a look at what [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has:

- `public final class String implements Comparable<String>`

  - `String` defines its natural ordering as case-sensitive
- It has a field

  - [`public static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

    - Here we have a case-insensitive custom `Comparator<String>`

An example of using this is the following:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
        Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "aa", "bb", "cc")
    );

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    // prints "[A, B, C, aa, bb, cc]"

    Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    System.out.println(list);
    // prints "[A, aa, B, bb, C, cc]"
```

Here's an example of sorting `List<String>` using both its natural ordering and your own custom `Comparator<String>`. Note that we've defined our own `Comparator<String>` without even changing the `final class String` itself.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
        Arrays.asList("1", "000000", "22", "100")
    );
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    // prints "[000000, 1, 100, 22]" natural lexicographical ordering

    Comparator<String> lengthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(s1.length())
                .compareTo(s2.length());
        }           
    };
    Collections.sort(list, lengthComparator);
    System.out.println(list);
    // prints "[1, 22, 100, 000000]" ordered by length

    Comparator<String> integerParseComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(s1))
                .compareTo(Integer.parseInt(s2));
        }           
    };
    Collections.sort(list, integerParseComparator);
    System.out.println(list);
    // prints "[000000, 1, 22, 100]" ordered by their values as integers
```

---

#### Conclusion

You can follow the example set by `String`, and do something like this:

```
public class Check implements Comparable<Check> {

   public static final Comparator<Check> NUMBER_ORDER = ...
   public static final Comparator<Check> AMOUNT_ORDER = ...
   public static final Comparator<Check> SOMETHING_ELSE_ORDER = ...

}
```

Then you can sort a `List<Check>` as follows:

```
List<Check> checks = ...;
Collections.sort(checks, Check.AMOUNT_ORDER);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the OP's question - even though it does contain a lot of good info.

Comment: I have to use a raw type its one of the assignment rquirments